# Specify fllename without user interaction?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

I have horrible piece of code that I simply want to specify the input file myself instead of popping up any type of dialog box to the user. I know this code is ancient, but hopefully some wise-man can answer this quickly for it's simple, I'm sure, but i'm not a programmer.

```
BOOL Geeeez()
{
    BOOL ret=FALSE;
    NavDialogRef fileDialog;
    NavDialogCreationOptions fo;
    NavGetDefaultDialogCreationOptions(&fo);
    fo.optionFlags=0;
    fo.parentWindow=win;
    NavCreateChooseFileDialog(&fo,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,&fileDialog);
    if (!NavDialogRun(fileDialog)) {
        NavReplyRecord r;
        if (!NavDialogGetReply(fileDialog,&r)) {
            AEKeyword k;
            FSRef fr;
            if (!AEGetNthPtr(&r.selection,1,typeFSRef,&k,NULL,&fr,sizeof(fr),NULL)) {
                char file[256];
                FSRefMakePath(&fr,(BYTE*)file,sizeof(file));
                if (!(data=THIS_CodeReallySucks(FALSE,file,0,0,NULL))
                ......
```

Comment: What it is, is Carbon... what Noah wants, is for somebody to re-write it to remove the `NavDialogRef` stuff.  What Noah ought to say is:  does the result need to continue to be Carbon or should it be Objective C, since that's what you've tagged this question with?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann, true. if i knew how to do it i wouldn't have asked. sure it would be nice to update it to objective-c, although as long as it works i don't mind if it stays in it's prehistoric form.

Answer (score 1):

All that code is doing is asking the user to choose a file, and then eventually converting the File System Reference into a C-string containing the path. If you know the path, the above code can be reduced to:

```
BOOL Geeeez()
{
    if (!(data = THIS_CodeReallySucks(FALSE, "path to file goes here", 0, 0, NULL))
    ...
```

Comment: yes... I'm also guessing that the path needs to be POSIX in this case (i.e. colon delineated... e.g. `"Macintosh HD:Users:Noah:Desktop:somefile.txt"`).

Comment: @user1118321, yeah that's a bit obvious, i'm looking for more specifics on how **exactly** it needs to be. Something tells me it's not as straight forward as it appears. --MichaelDautermann, thanks for the hint, but a guess won't do me much good. Doesn't carbon have any similar code such as NSBundle, NSHomeDirectory, etc? the file will be in the resources, that's why i ask.

Comment: Yes, Carbon has CFBundle. What exactly are you trying to do? Your question said you wanted to get the file without using an open file dialog, and that you already knew its path. If you know it's path, you can skip everything involved in getting the path. So what is it you're really trying to do? You need to write a clearer question if you want a better answer.